# How to reset a Linux event descriptor created with EFD_SEMAPHORE

Tags: linux, polling, epoll, dup2

I have an event descriptor that was created in C code like this:

```
int notifyED = eventfd(0, EFD_SEMAPHORE | EFD_CLOEXEC);
```

The counter goes up and down as expected as a result of calls to `eventfd_read()` and `eventfd_write()`.

All good so far. Now I want to "flush" the 64-bit counter within this event FD so that it resets to zero.

- The flush operation needs to be "transparent" to any poll/epoll instance that is monitoring the event FD.
- After the flush, any polling instance should not generate a new POLLIN until a further `eventfd_write()` happens.

**Obviously the semaphore-like semantics will prevent the counter being reset in a single read() operation**, so I have implemented the flush this way:

```
int flushED = eventfd(0, EFD_SEMAPHORE);

notifyED = dup3(flushED, notifyED, O_CLOEXEC);
close(flushED);
```

If I understand the documentation pages for `dup()` and its variants correctly, `dup3()` should atomically close and reassign the event descriptor. N.B. the program always explicitly calls `close(notifyED)` before it exits.

**EDIT**: updated to use `dup3()` to maintain the CLOEXEC flag and to incorporate feedback in comments about closing both descriptors.

Alternative solutions I am already aware of:

1. for epoll specifically, use ctl_add() and ctl_del() to replace the descriptor with a new one;
2. repeatedly call `eventfd_read()` until the counter is zero.

**Specific questions:**

1. Is the `dup3()` approach acceptable ?
2. Am I leaking descriptor resources at all ?
3. From my testing, an epoll instance seems to behave as expected. Any gotchas I have missed ?

Comment: Are you aware that you must close both file handles when calling `dup2()`?

Comment: Thanks @MartinRosenau: no I was not aware, hence my specific question about resource leakage. Perhaps I should separate the single call into a tempED = eventfd(0,EFD_SEMAPHORE) first and then pass that temp descriptor into the dup2() and close(tempED) explicitly afterwards ?